# groovysh: how to deal with a typo

Tags: groovy, groovyshell, groovysh

This seems like a really silly question, but when I use `groovysh`, if I have a typo, it seems to kill the entire shell.

For example, if I want to iterate through an array, I can do this `arr.each { elt ->`.  But if I accidentally type `arr.each { elt =>`, then every future line I type results in

```
groovysh_parse: 2: unexpected token: > @ line 2, column 13.
   arr.each { elt =>
               ^
```

I can't get back to a working shell without killing the shell and restarting it, which means I lose all the work I've done in the shell.

Is there a way to get out of this?

Comment: Probably better to use groovyConsole if you need to type a lot of code.

Comment: running over SSH so I can't use a gui.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple ways to get out of this. One is to clear the entire buffer using `:c`. The other is to edit the current buffer and fix your typo using `:e`.

In older versions of Groovy, the command prefix was '\' i.e. `\c` and `\e`.